# Uploaded photo via Facebook's Open Graph API isn't centered in Timeline thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook does not correctly center the Timeline photo thumbnail when I upload the photo (810x694) via Open Graph API (POST /me/photos). However, when I manually attach the photo as a status update, the Timeline photo thumbnail is centered properly. Is there a request parameter, fix, or workaround for this?

**Photo uploaded via OG API:**
[image: Photo uploaded via OG API]
**Photo posted as a status update:**
[image: Photo posted as a status update]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally overlooked this, the issue was related to tagged friends in the photo. I changed the tag position to the center/50% to resolve the issue.